# PHPUnit Mysteriously Fails On Object Constructor with require_once and $SERVER variable

Tags: php, netbeans, phpunit

I'm trying to wrap a test class around a pre-existing PHP class file that does not adhere to any PSR standard.

The PHP object I'm trying to test has a constructor that accepts 1 argument.

When prepping my object in setUp, my test correctly fails because there is a constructor argument missing. Because of this, I feel good that my object is being correctly resolved.

```
protected function setUp() {
    $this->object = new HierarchyChange();
}
```

However, when I do add a value:

```
$this->object = new HierarchyChange('username');
```

NetBeans throws a "Perhaps error occurred, verify in Output window" message when I run the tests. And the output window has no information.

Executing "phpunit . -v" from the command line simply outputs the PHPUnit version I'm working with, but does not show any exception information.

I've tracked the failing line in my HierarchyChange class to this line in the class constructor:

```
public function __construct($agent_manager)
    {

        /* require contracting base class */
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/_inc/oc.class.php');
```

I've tried a number of different ways to add this file, thinking that the server variable was causing the problem, but even removing it and hardcoding the path in the constructor cause the test suite to crash.

It DOES, however, work when I comment out the require_once line completely.

It doesn't make sense to me why this fails, but I am grasping at straws with this. Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried using `require` instead of `require_once`? Not sure how the rest of your code is structured, but maybe it's not getting included when it needs to because of `_once`?

Comment: @JakeB. I have, as well as `include`; they still fail. And the HierarchyChange class contains no procedural code, including any other include or require statements, outside of the class.

Comment: Maybe add `error_reporting(-1);` to the top so PHP is more explicit with what's causing the error.

Comment: Have you resolved this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stemmed from a few things:

1. incorrect configuration of PHP.ini (error messages were not being raised), but more importantly:
2. incorrectly setting server vars; I ended up modifying the phpunit.xml configuration file to include:

Since the tests were being executed via CLI, these server variables are not available, so they needed to be set. And when phpunit encountered this as an error, NetBeans didn't know how to report it in the output window because the local INI configuration was not set to do so.

Comment: Can you describe more detailed what config parameters set in php.ini and phpunit.xml? Because I received "Perhaps error occurred, verify in Output window." error in NetBeans without any important data in the Output but I still can test with phpunit from command line. BTW, I use phpunit in command line without php. Can I run it the same way in Netbeans?

Comment: @DmytroZarezenko make sure display_errors = On is set in php.ini. That should be sufficient to get exception output. If you have configured NB test options correctly with phpunit (bootstrap and xml config) then you should be able to run the tests within the test runner. Where it gets finicky is configuring phpunit to point to the correct paths for things like your local server variables and your autoloader file, but having the right error config should help you track down any of those issues.